# Returning dynamic properties - Neo4j Client

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

In my application I create a node based on properties supplied by the user e.g. I create a node of type `Score` (the type does not change) and properties such as `TeamA`, `TeamB` but those are dynamic (user can type whatever they want as property). How can I retrieve dynamic properties of that node later ? Neo4j client is forcing me to create a class of type `Score` with fixed properties e.g. `.Return(score=> score.As<Score>().**FIXED_PROPERTY_NAME**);` but I want to pass the name of dynamic property there e.g. `TeamA`, how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is that you can't do it the way you're trying to. As you said neo4jclient is strongly typed. You can get around this by passing the response yourself into a dynamic type in the same way as this answer: [Casting nodes of an unknown type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860074/casting-nodes-of-an-unknown-type/21874771#21874771)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
WITH ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4'] AS properties
MATCH(score:Score)
WHERE score.cond = "some condition"
UNWIND properties AS key
WITH COLLECT([key, score[key]]) AS pairs
RETURN apoc.map.fromPairs(pairs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating `Score` class with properties `TeamA and TeamB`,

Create generalized class with a dictionary as property and maintain
`TeamA and TeamB` as keys.

I answered similar question in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45826714/1605761).