# How to return the whole node with all its properties from Neo4J .NET client?

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm trying to make a generic code that can filter on object connected to an user. These objects can be of different types, with different properties etc.

Basically I want to implement this method:

```
public string GetRelatedObjects(string sourceObject, string userId){
  var resQuery = GraphDB.Cypher
    .Match("(src:" + sourceObject + ")--(usr:User { Id:{userId} })")
    .WithParam("userId", userId)
    .Return(src => src.As<object>());
  var result = await resQuery.ResultsAsync;

  return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
}
```

The issue is when I use `.As<object>()` I get back an empty item.

When I put a concrete type, such as `.As<User>()` I get back the results I expect. Is there a way to get what I'm trying to get with Neo4JClient or do I have to go lower level somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So under the hood Neo4jClient uses Json.NET to deserialize the output from Neo4j into the class you specify. As you specify `object` which has no properties you get no properties. Neither Neo4jClient nor Json.NET know what your actually after, so you can only get the `object` back. Now, solution time - you can use `dynamic` instead.

```
public async Task<string> GetRelatedObjectsAsJson(string sourceObject, string userId)
{
    var resQuery = GraphDB.Cypher
        .Match(string.Format("(src:{0})--(usr:User {{ Id:{{userId}} }})", sourceObject))
        .WithParam("userId", userId)
        .Return(src => src.As<Node<string>>());
    var result = await resQuery.ResultsAsync;

    var output = result.Select(node => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(node.Data)).ToList();
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output);
}
```

I think this will get what you want, if *I* were you, I would probably return an `Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>>` instead of reserializing to a `string`, but I don't know what you want to use the results for, so maybe not appropriate.

Please see [Casting nodes of an unknown type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860074/casting-nodes-of-an-unknown-type) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can return node with all its properties by creating generalized node class.

Precisely, It can be done by

- Creating Generalized "GenNode" Class
- Casting your result as GenNode

***C# Class :***

```
public class GenNode
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<String> Labels { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<String, String> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

***Rewritten Method :***

```
public IEnumerable<GenNode> GetRelatedObjects(string sourceObject, string userId){
var resQuery = GraphDB.Cypher
    .Match("(src:" + sourceObject + ")--(usr:User { Id:{userId} })")
    .WithParam("userId", userId)
    .With("src, properties(src) as prop")
    .Return((src,prop) => new GenNode
    {
      Id = src.Id(),
      Labels = src.Labels(),
      Properties = prop.As<Dictionary<Object,Object>>()
    });

  var result = await resQuery.ResultsAsync;

  return result;
}
```

*Pay attention to return type.*

Comment: I have not checked whether this code compiles or not. But it should clear the overall idea.