# Neo4jClient How can I return all nodes, relationships and parameters for a dynamic graph

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I am building an application where node labels, parameters and relationships are going to be set by my users, so nodes, rel, and prop after a certain layer will be completely dynamic and unpredictable. My question is how do I run the following query and map the results to some sort of list that can be used to rebuild the graph visually. Using neo4jClient.

The query I use directly with the Neo4j Browser works great

```
Match(a:User),(b:Work)-->(n) Where a.UserId = 
'xxxx' AND  b.Name = 'CompanyA' Return b, n
```

In c# I have this, but its the return part that I am stuck on.

```
 client.Cypher.Match("(a:User), (b:Work) --> (n)")
                .Where("(a.UserId = '" + userId + "')").AndWhere("(b.Name = name"
.Return((a,n)).Results;
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: I don't know if you're doing this but you should never concatenate a value given to you by a user into a query string because you open yourself up to injection attacks (where users could make up their Cypher and do whatever they want to your database).

Comment: The solution to that, by the way, is using Neo4j parameters.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I should be using best practices in all my code, and parameters are a must here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Neo4jClient` can't help you directly with this, the problem (from a C# point of view) is that the client attempts to deserialize the results into concrete C# types, and you're not supplying any...

Your best bet is to do the same as in the answer to this question (use `dynamic`): [Casting nodes of an unknown type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860074/casting-nodes-of-an-unknown-type/21874771#21874771)

So, you'll end up with something like:

```
var query = client.Cypher
    .Match("(a:User), (b:Work) --> (n)")
    .Where("a.UserId = {userIdParam}")
    .AndWhere("b.Name = {bNameParam}")
    .WithParams( new {
        userIdParam = userId,
        bNameParam = name
    })
    .Return((a,n) => new {
        A = a.As<User>(),
        N = n.As<Node<string>>()
    });

var results = query.Results.ToList();
var nNodes = new List<dynamic>();
foreach(var result in results)
{
    nNodes.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result.N.Data));
}
```

`nNodes` will then contain a collection of `dynamic` objects with which you can do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I just implemented your solution and it works as I was hoping.

Comment: Just to finish this out. I was also interested in getting the relationship as well. I worked out how to get the relationship types. by adding (a)-[r]->(b) and then in the .Return adding R = r.Type(). I am one step from getting everything here. How would I get the data from relationships? They may also be dynamic.

Comment: Off the top of my head - something like: `.Return(r => r.As<RelationshipObject<string>>()` I'm not 100% sure, and I'm not near a computer to check :/ if that doesn't work let me know and I'll see when I am near a comp

Comment: Hmm. That didn't quite work out. so `.ReturnInstance<TData>()` is I think what I want. This is useful though, when I use `ReturnInstance<object>` it provides me with the relationship directions from start nod to end node. But the data is returned as an object that I cant seem to get a meaningful string from.