# Neo4j Cypher Client Create Dynamic Objects

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

At the moment I have to specify what class is needed during the return, is there a way to get all properties and and create a dynamic/anonymous object.

```
public IEnumerable<Node> GetNodes()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Retrieving All Nodes from DB...");
        try
        {
            return graphClient.Cypher
               .Match($"(n:Node)")
               .Return(t => new Node
               {
                   Latitude = Return.As<double>("n.lat"),
                   Longitude = Return.As<double>("n.lon"),
                   Id = Return.As<string>("n.id"),
                   ValA = Return.As<long>("n.valA")
               }).Results;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = $"ERROR (Get Node): {ex.ToString()}";
            Console.WriteLine(error);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the [`Neo4J official C# driver`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Neo4j.Driver) and JSON.NET like:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string neo4jHostname = string.Empty, neo4jUsername = string.Empty, neo4jPassword = string.Empty;
    IDriver driver = GraphDatabase.Driver(neo4jHostname, AuthTokens.Basic(neo4jUsername, neo4jPassword));

    using (ISession session = driver.Session())
    {
        string query = "MATCH (n) RETURN n";
        IStatementResult resultCursor = session.Run(query);
        List<IRecord> res = resultCursor.ToList();
        string values = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res.Select(x => x.Values), Formatting.Indented);
        List<JObject> nodes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JObject>>(values);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the solution I wrote for this question: [Neo4jClient How can I return all nodes, relationships and parameters for a dynamic graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917863/neo4jclient-how-can-i-return-all-nodes-relationships-and-parameters-for-a-dynam)

I would argue - if this is what you really want to do - you might be better off using the official driver (Neo4j-Driver) or indeed just using a standard REST client and connecting directly - however - the above answer should get you going where you want to be!