# How get relationship's startNodeId and endNodeId using Neo4jClient?

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

```
var query = client.Cypher
             .Match("(n1)-[r]-[n2]")
             .Where("n1.NodeId={startNodeId} and n2.NodeId={endNodeId}")
             .WithParam("startNodeId",startNodeId)
             .withParam("endNodeId",endNodeId)
             .return((r,n1,n2)=>new {Edge=r.As<Node<string>>(),Type=r.Type()});
```

By this way,I can only get the relationship's **Label** and **Properties**.But I also want to get the relationship's startNodeId and endNodeId.
By the way,I can get the relationship's startNodeId and endNodeId by using REST API.
How can anyone help me?

Z.Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you're meaning by `startNodeId` - if you mean the `Neo4j` Ids, then you'll be wanting to use the `Relationship<T>` class:

```
client.Cypher
    .Match("(n1)-[r]-(n2)")
    //Your where stuff here.
    .Return(r => r.As<RelationshipInstance<string>());
```

The `T` should be a type you've put on the relationship, but if you haven't got that, just use `object`, you **will** need to use the `Relationship<T>` type, you can't use the non-generic version.

If the `startNodeId` is a property on a type, then you either do `r => r.As<YourType>()` or `r => r.As<Relationship<YourType>>()`.

As a side note, you can use `Neo4jClient`s ability to parse parameters and save some code (also make it *more* compile safe) with respect to your `Where` clauses.

I would write your code as:

```
var query = client.Cypher
    .Match("(n1)-[r]-[n2]")
    .Where((NodeType n1) => n1.NodeId == startNodeId)
    .AndWhere((NodeType n2) => n2.NodeId == endNodeId)
    .Return(r => new { Edge = r.As<RelationshipInstance<object>>(), Type = r.Type()});
```

which auto parses the parameters.

Comment: I want to get the Neo4j Ids of startNodeId and endNodeId from the relationship that returned.I tried your method,but I meet exception when I compliling.
the error :
System.ArgumentException
You've called As<relationship`1>() in your clause,where Relationship`1 is not a supported type.It must be a simple type(like int,string,or long)......

Comment: Sorry - it should have been `RelationshipInstance` - if you read the whole error message you'll see at the end it mentions that. - If that doesn't help - I think you need to edit your question with the Cypher that gets you what you want, and we can go from there!

Comment: Thx，Chris Skardon, I found what I want by using RelationshipInstance!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the classes which you want to cast to you can use:

```
var results= client.Cypher
             .Match("(n1)-[r]-[n2]")
             .Where("n1.NodeId={startNodeId} and n2.NodeId={endNodeId}")
             .WithParam("startNodeId",startNodeId)
             .withParam("endNodeId",endNodeId)
.Return((n1, r1 n2) => new {Edge=r.As<Node<string>>(),Type=r.Type()}, Class1= n1.As<Class1>(), Class2= n2.As<Class2>()})
.Results;
```

Then you can iterate through the results. If only one result is expected its first item in the 'results' array

Comment: uh,I just want to know how to distinguish the startNode and endNode,so I tried to get the imformation from the relationship.And r.As<Node<string>>() just contains relationship's Label and properties.

Comment: If you want to get the labels of a node use n1.Labels(). If you don't know the type the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860074/casting-nodes-of-an-unknown-type explains Casting nodes of an unknown type