# How to deserialise objects with the correct type of a node from Neo4j?

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j, neo4jclient

We have paths of nodes which represent a set of activities which can happen linear or also parallel. These paths include multiple different types of nodes. Now I'm building a REST Api to get all the nodes of a path and display them on my frontend.

Since all this happens in c# I have to get the type so that I can create my object accordingly. It's not a problem to call cyphers which return me a specific type, since I can simply do it like this :

```
        public List<Todo> Get()
        {
            var query = client.Cypher
                                    .Match("(n: Todo)")
                                    .Return((n) => n.As<Todo>());

            return query.Results.ToList();
        }
```

But how would I approach this when I get multiple different types from my cypher?

Comment: Do you mean when you don't know what `n` is (in your case) i.e. it could be `Todo` or something else?

Comment: Does this post do what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860074/casting-nodes-of-an-unknown-type/21874771#21874771

Comment: @ChrisSkardon Yes to both of your questions, I solves this with anonymous types, which I was not aware of until now. So I guess I can close this question and mark it as redundant and link to the question you have provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since neo4j's legacy REST API will be dropped in neo4j 4.0, I assume you are planning on using the [Cypher transaction API](https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/current/actions/).

When you pass a Cypher statement to the transactional API, you can specify the [graph](https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/current/actions/return-results-in-graph-format/#http-api-return-results-in-graph-format) option in the `resultDataContents` list. That will cause the response to include the node labels and relationship types.